# Error in Set and Unset watermark Request using Youtube Data API V3

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using

```
        IDE       :     VS2012  
        Framework :     4.0
        Google API:     Youtube Data V3
        Authentication: Outh 2.0
```

I am using **Youtube Data API V3** to set watermark on youtube video . Here is my code

`**my fiddler request**` is : POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/watermarks/set?channelId=UCyAn2aVZWNAugdlckOJKG5A

and my **content body** :
    {
     "position": {
      "cornerPosition": "topRight",
      "type": "corner"
     },
     "timing": {
      "durationMs": "50000",
      "offsetMs": "1000",
      "type": "offsetFromStart"
     },
     "targetChannelId": "UCyAn2aVZWNAugdlckOJKG5A"
    }

i am passing image content with stream object with set method ..

and  **Response is**: **Value cannot be null Parameter name: baseUri**

```
public async Task setwatermark()
        {

        InvideoBranding ib = new InvideoBranding();
        InvideoTiming it = new InvideoTiming();
        InvideoPosition ip = new InvideoPosition();
        Stream stream = null; 
        it.Type = "offsetFromStart";
        it.OffsetMs = 1000;
        it.DurationMs = 50000;

        ip.Type = "corner";
        ip.CornerPosition = "topRight";

        string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/orderedList0.png");
        ib.TargetChannelId = "UCyAn2aVZWNAugdlckOJKG5A";
     //   ib.ImageUrl = filepath;
        ib.Position = ip;
        ib.Timing = it;


        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            stream = (Stream)fileStream;
            var setrequest = youtubeService.Watermarks.Set(ib, "UCyAn2aVZWNAugdlckOJKG5A",stream,"image/*");
            var resp =await setrequest.UploadAsync();


        }
```

Below code is for unset watermarks using YouTube Data API V3.
It is response with --Error 503-backend error.

**Fiddler Request** :POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/watermarks/unset?channelId=UCyAn2aVZWNAugdlckOJKG5A

```
    **Fiddler response**  :{
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "back end Error",
        "message": "Back end Error"
       }

  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "Back end Error"
 }
```

}

```
 private void Unsetwatermark()
        {


        var unsetrequest = youtubeService.Watermarks.Unset("UCyAn2aVZWNAugdlckOJKG5A");

        var searchListResponse = unsetrequest.Execute();





    }
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong for both above mentioned  api request ..

Comment: Can you please attach the HTTP request and response (using fiddler). Remember to exclude the Authorization header :)

Comment: i have attached here fiddler request and respnonse here..